# Programmatically set Global settings in Android

Tags: java, android

I am workig on a project for business phones running on an Android OS. I would like to have some settings pre set on the phone.

Is there a way to programatically set these settings, using something like a "Settings App" which would set the settings on startup?

Maybe you can help me sort out which settings are possible and which are not.

- Time / TimeZone
- APN
- USB Debugging
- Unknown Sources
- Location Services
- Screen Brightness

As I understand, you can not set the settings under Settings.Global, but there is a class Settings.System which apparently allows to set some settings. (Most are deprecated, as I understand I can not use them anymore).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First issue you may run into is most settings are allowed by ROOT process only. You need to grant root access to your app, but doing it automatically without user interaction might be a showstopper. Chicken-egg problem I guess.

Comment: Yes, that is what I fear. Is there a way to use deprecated methods,  maybe?

Comment: screen brightness: http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/changing-screen-brightness.html.. Apart from that doing all this thing in background is not possible without Rooted device..

Comment: Ok, thanks for your confirmation I will redirect this to the manufacturer.